# select the max record from table

Tags: sql, firebird, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table which contains `Order_id`, `hour`, `location_code`. Each record corresponds to an order ID, the location it is placed and the time it was registered in that location, such as the sample as follows:

```
ORDER_ID |            HOUR       |LOCATION_CODE
10910568 | 1899-12-30 04:25:40   |   168
10910568 | 1899-12-30 00:44:04   |   96
10910568 | 1899-12-30 04:18:00   |  217
10910568 | 1899-12-30 04:25:41   |    6
10910569 | 1899-12-30 04:25:40   |  168
10910569 | 1899-12-30 00:44:04   |   96
10910569 | 1899-12-30 04:18:00   |  217
10910569 | 1899-12-30 04:25:42   |    7
```

The expect result I need is:

```
ORDER_ID |       HOUR           |LOCATION_CODE
10910568 | 1899-12-30 04:25:41  |      6
10910569 | 1899-12-30 04:25:42  |      7
```

The original table is very large so I need to extract this information for every `ORDER_ID`.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: if "original table Is large" you would be better **creating a helper caching table** where you would keep those per-ORDER row ID's that you need. You may use triggers to keep it up to date. Or to invalidate it when master table changes and to re-create cache for missing rows before request

Comment: Also, what is your target Firebird version ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table is very large I suggest that you get the max `HOUR` for each `ORDER_ID` in a query with a simple `GROUP BY ORDER_ID` and join to the table:

```
select t.*
from tablename t inner join (
  select order_id, max(hour) maxhour
  from tablename
  group by order_id
) g on g.order_id = t.order_id and g.maxhour = t.hour
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=38e854b1cb2d2f1c6bd194dbffb387a7).
Results:

```
| ORDER_ID | HOUR                | LOCATION_CODE |
| -------- | ------------------- | ------------- |
| 10910568 | 1899-12-30 04:25:41 | 6             |
| 10910569 | 1899-12-30 04:25:42 | 7             |
```

Comment: This demo is not using Firebird, try https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0

Comment: @Arioch'The good to know there is a fiddle for Firebird (although I should have known since I use this site often mainly for SQL Server fiddles, I never noticed!!!)

Comment: starting point: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=40772c21070e62ff1863147b654b0f13

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using row_number()

```
    Select ORDER_ID, hour,   
      LOCATION_CODE from (select 
       ORDER_ID, hour,   
      LOCATION_CODE, row_number()
     over (partition by order_id order by
     Hour desc) rn from table) t where
      t.rn=1
```

Comment: And if Firebird 3 is used perhaps this would be better option on average...

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.* 
from mytable t
where hour = (select max(t1.hour) from mytable t1 where t1.order_id = t.order_id)
```

With an index on `(order_id, hour)`, this should be a very efficient solution.

Alternatively, you may also want to use `order by` and `first 1` in the subquery instead of aggregation:

```
select t.* 
from mytable t
where hour = (
    select first 1 hour from mytable t1 where t1.order_id = t.order_id order by hour desc
)
```